# Identifier 'user' has already been declared

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, node-modules

I'm learning JavaScript, I'm making a bot discord with `switch`, `case` and `break` (to test). I have a problem, when I do two commands using the same constant name, it gives me an error. I would like that for example, **user** is read only if the command is written. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Code:

```js
case "avatar":
     const user = message.mentions.users.first() || client.users.cache.get(args[0]) || await client.users.fetch(args[0]) ||  message.author
     if (!user) return message.edit(`Aucun utilisateur de trouvé pour \`${args[0] || "rien"}\``)
     message.edit(`Voici l'avatar de **${user.tag}**:\n${user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true, size: 4096})}`)
     break;

case "userinfo":
     if (!message.guild) return message.edit("Commande utilisable uniquement sur un serveur")
     const user = message.mentions.members.first() || client.members.cache.get(args[0]) || await client.members.fetch(args[0]) ||  message.member
     if (!user) return message.edit(`Aucun utilisateur de trouvé pour \`${args[0] || "rien"}\``)
     break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You could enclose the code after each `case:` in `{` and `}`

Each `user` declaration is therefore in a separate block, and therefore a separate scope. That should allow you to use the same variable name in different blocks, which you presumably want to do, to make it easier to read and understand your code.

```
case "avatar": {
     const user = message.mentions.users.first() || client.users.cache.get(args[0]) || await client.users.fetch(args[0]) ||  message.author
     if (!user) return message.edit(`Aucun utilisateur de trouvé pour \`${args[0] || "rien"}\``)
     message.edit(`Voici l'avatar de **${user.tag}**:\n${user.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true, size: 4096})}`)
     break;
}

case "userinfo": {
     if (!message.guild) return message.edit("Commande utilisable uniquement sur un serveur")
     const user = message.mentions.members.first() || client.members.cache.get(args[0]) || await client.members.fetch(args[0]) ||  message.member
     if (!user) return message.edit(`Aucun utilisateur de trouvé pour \`${args[0] || "rien"}\``)
     break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know I could put `{}`!

Answer (score -1):

Constants are variables that cannot be redeclared or reassigned within the same scope, so you can't use the same constant name for different variables. Especially with `switch .. case` all cases belong to the same scope (if you don't make a block with {} for each of them), which is causing the issue here.

Comment: While that is true, you should also have mentioned, that especially with `switch .. case` all cases belong to the same scope (if you don't make a block with `{}` for each of them), which is causing the issue here ...